# How to assign the same value to all elements of an array

Tags: php, file-type

Sorry, I don't know how to really word this question. I have an app where you can specify filetypes to be hidden from certain users like so:

```
$config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users']['108'] = array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
```

The above line would hide all .ftpquota files from user #108. I am trying to hide filetypes from ALL users. I have tried:

```
$config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users'][''] = array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
$config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users'][] = array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
$config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users']['*'] = array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
$config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users'][*] = array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
$config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users'] = array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
```

Would anyone have an idea as to how I can specify ALL users?

Comment: We have no idea what application you're trying to configure

Comment: This is 100% dependent on how whomever wrote that code and array setting implemented it.

Comment: Funny...someone posted their FIRST post to stackoverflow and was able to answer the question. My question was not app dependent.

Comment: @JohnRobinson Don't be discourage John, some of the power users with 20k+ rep can be mean and/or troll.  It's just part of the SO culture.

Comment: If I knew exactly what I was talking about, I wouldnt have needed to ask a question. I did know enough to know that it wasn't totally app dependent, which is why I posted the question here. Someone was kind enough to post a working and helpful answer, and I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know what all the indeces of the array are, you can just loop through all the values and set them all to the desired one using [foreach](http://www.php.net/foreach).

```
foreach($config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users'] as $index => $value)
{
    $config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users'][$index] = Array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach ($config['app']['custom_hidden_files']['users'] as $user)
 {
    $user=array("*.ftpquota", "*.FTPQUOTA");
 }
```